# Snake and ladders: how to show the dices we chose in snakes and ladders shortest path problem?

Tags: python

The input is represented by two things, first is ‘N’ which is number of cells in the given board, second is an array ‘move[0…N-1]’ of size N. An entry move[i] is -1 if there is no snake and no ladder from i, otherwise move[i] contains index of destination cell for the snake or the ladder at i.
**can someone tell me how to show the dices we chose in the shortest path in this code?**
right now it just shows the min of the time we throw the dice with BFS and queues , and I want to know how to show the dices we choose. I would appreciate any help.

```
# Python3 program to find minimum number 
class QueueEntry(object): 
def __init__(self, v = 0, dist = 0): 
    self.v = v 
    self.dist = dist
def getMinDiceThrows(move, N):
  # The graph has N vertices. Mark all 
  # the vertices as not visited 
  visited = [False] * N
  # Create a queue for BFS 
  queue = []
  # Mark the node 0 as visited and enqueue it 
  visited[0] = True
  # Distance of 0't vertex is also 0 
  # Enqueue 0'th vertex 
 queue.append(QueueEntry(0, 0))
 # Do a BFS starting from vertex at index 0 
 qe = QueueEntry()  # A queue entry (qe) 
 while queue:
    qe = queue.pop(0)
    v = qe.v # Vertex no. of queue entry 
    # If front vertex is the destination 
    # vertex, we are done 
    if v == N - 1:
        break

    # Otherwise dequeue the front vertex  
    # and enqueue its adjacent vertices  
    # (or cell numbers reachable through 
    # a dice throw) 
    j = v + 1
    while j <= v + 6 and j < N:
        # If this cell is already visited, 
        # then ignore 
        if visited[j] is False:
            # Otherwise calculate its  
            # distance and mark it  
            # as visited 
            a = QueueEntry()
            a.dist = qe.dist + 1
            visited[j] = True

            # Check if there a snake or ladder 
            # at 'j' then tail of snake or top 
            # of ladder become the adjacent of 'i'
            a.v = move[j] if move[j] != -1 else j
            queue.append(a)
        j += 1
# We reach here when 'qe' has last vertex 
# return the distance of vertex in 'qe 
return qe.dist
```

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**. Help us help you. Please elaborate a bit about what your algorithm is supposed to do and how it works so we can help you better.

Comment: Please check your indentation, and show in the code where you "throw a die", as there's nothing indicating what particular piece of code you're trying to save/display